# SSIS 2012 Project deployment and SSISDB creation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

what version of SQL server is required to created SSISDB catalog for project deployment model? I have downloaded SSDT 2012 and now I am trying to test project deployment model in my dev environment.

Can I use 2012 sql server Express edition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I will need sql server developer edition on my machine to deploy with new Project deployment model